# Add Ordered Number To Filtered List Formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a filter formula

```
=IFERROR(FILTER("MS - " & RawDataMS!$G$2:G & " " & RawDataMS!$H$2:H & " - " & RawDataMS!$T$2:T, DATEVALUE(RawDataMS!$A$2:A) > DATEVALUE(DropdownValues!$N$2), RawDataMS!$S$2:S = DropdownValues!$K$8),)
```

That builds a list

MS - Chloe Cervantes - 7th Grade
MS - James Wellington - 7th Grade
MS - Clara Rodman - 6th Grade
MS - Briar Wallace - 7th Grade

**How do I add an ordered number to the list?**

e.g.

**1.** MS - Chloe Cervantes - 7th Grade
**2.** MS - James Wellington - 7th Grade
**3.** MS - Clara Rodman - 6th Grade
**4.** MS - Briar Wallace - 7th Grade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps at all.
Can you replace the IFERROR array that I've used in the following formula, with your formula?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SEQUENCE(COUNTA({IFERROR(FILTER(A2:A5,A2:A5<>""),)}))&". "& 
                  {IFERROR(FILTER(A2:A5,A2:A5<>""),)})
```

[image]